# Using multiple return statements in a method

Tags: java, set, return, pojo

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Speler
{

    public String naam;
    public String aantalKeerGespeeld;
    public String behaaldePunten;
    public String spelersInfo;


    public String setNaam(){
        return naam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe heet je?");
    }

    public String setAantalKeerGespeeld(){
        return aantalKeerGespeeld = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe vaak heb je gespeeld?");
    }

    public String setBehaaldePunten(){
        return behaaldePunten = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe veel punten heb je behaald?");
    }

    public String setSpelersInfo(){
        **return naam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe heet je?");
        return aantalKeerGespeeld = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe vaak heb je gespeeld?");
        return behaaldePunten = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hoe veel punten heb je behaald?");**


    }
    public String getNaam(){
        return naam;
    }

    public String getAantalKeerGespeeld(){
        return aantalKeerGespeeld;
    }

    public String getBehaaldePunten(){
        return behaaldePunten;
    }

    public String getSpelersinfo(){
        return naam;
        return aantalKeerGespeeld;
        return behaaldePunten;
    }
}
```

Looks like I can't return or set more than 1 value. Just began learning Java, and it's hard to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

After looking more closely at your code, I would like to clear up what appear to be a few misunderstandings. First of all, from what I can see, you don't need to return multiple values from any of your methods. In fact, a method name that starts with the word "set" shouldn't return anything at all. On the other hand, it needs to take a parameter in order to "set" the value of a variable. For example

```
public void setNaam(String newNaam){
    naam = newNaam;
}
```

Note that I don't use a JOptionPane dialog to get the name. At this point in the code, we don't care where the value came from. Some other method is responsible for actually getting the value from the user. This method simply stores the value for later use.

Also, note that you have a field declared as

```
String spelersInfo;
```

I believe the `getSpelersInfo()` and `setSpelersInfo()` should use this, which is why I claim that you don't need to return multiple values from either of these methods.

Finally, it appears that you are creating what we call a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object). See this link for more details about what the acronym means.

Answer (score 2):

The basics of a `return` statement is that it causes the program to leave the current function(subroutine) and resume from where the function was called, which is the return address.
When you enter a function the return address is saved on the call stack so its easily reachable.

So as for your code, when you issue a `return` statement and then another one, the latter will not be called.
If I'm not mistaken, it will not be even compiled on most compilers.
    Hence what you need to do is issue a return statement that returns all the String's together.
That can be done with many basic [Data Structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure) that are available in the Java standard library and if you don't want to get involved in that, you could even append the strings into one big string and then split it after.

But for now what I would suggest is to read a basic Java book/[tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm) or even a basic book about programming languages.
Goodluck!

[Link to some basic Java Data structures](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_data_structures.htm)

**Edit**
As Code-Guru pointed out and is correct, the best way to approach this issue is with a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), you can see a nice explanation in his answer.

Though reading a book and understanding the fundamentals in my opinion beats all of the technical solutions at this point

Comment: +1 For explaining how return works. In the context of the given code, using a Container doesn't seem appropriate. The OP is creating a POJO.

Comment: You are right, thanks for that, I will add your comment into my answer, and +1 for ur input

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't return more than one value in that way.

The way the `return` keyword works is that it will immediately return control back to the calling code, using the returned value as the value of the function. The first return call it sees will exit the function itself, so any subsequent code will never be executed.

Generally, you shouldn't have to ever need to return multiple values from a function in that manner. However, if you want to return a list of values, you can pack them into a Container object (such as an object of `java.util.Vector`) and return the vector object. However, it doesn't appear that is necessary in any of your code that you listed.

In the code you posted, however, it seems like instead of returning values from the function, you want to have your instance variables of your class be set by the `JOptionPane` prompts. Then you just have a single `return` statement at the end of the function once all those assignments complete. Note that if your function is declared as `void` (that is, it doesn't return a value), you don't need to have a `return;` line at the end, as once it reaches the end of the method, it will exit. Sometimes having `return;` is useful (such as if you have multiple return points) but that is a topic for study at another time.

Comment: +1 For explaining how return works. In the context of the given code, using a Container doesn't seem appropriate. The OP is creating a POJO.

Comment: That is true. I tried to use it as an example of how one would return multiple values, though I agree that in his code above, it would not be necessary. I edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Many modern languages have the elegant capability to return multiple values, but java does not.  As a practical matter, you have to choose something else.  The 100% acceptable solution from the viewpoint of everything but efficiency is to return a new object of a new class designed to hold the set of return values.  ie;

class TwoStrings { String name; String addres;  ... }

and in your code return(new TwoStrings("foo","bar"));

Another fully acceptable choice is to refactor your interface so it is natural to
return the values one at a time.  If you wanted "getXandY(), refactor it as getX() and getY()

A frequent choice is to make the container for return values one of the parameters of
the callee. Instead of returning "name" and "address", supply a "person" to the function
which it will load with name and address (and presumably return an indicator of success).

Less acceptable ways are to use non-specfic arrays or vectors to return multiple values

Least acceptable is to return one value, and stash the other values for use by the
caller "return by side effect"

Answer (score -1):

Yes you are correct, You cannot have more than one return statement in a method. How about returning an POJO back to the caller method and get the value there?

Comment: If you look closely at the code, the OP *is* creating a POJO. Returning a different POJO from a setter wouldn't make much sense.